# How to enable "use continuation indent for arguments" option

Tags: pycharm

settings -> editor -> code style -> python -> "other" tab -> check "use continuation indent for arguments"

When I check it,

- The apply button remains in defunct state, as if no change was done
- On clicking "ok" button, the setting is not saved, it remains unchecked when the dialog is opened next time.